# Is there any way to get same encryption key while encrypting a same data?

Tags: reactjs, encryption, password-encryption, encryption-symmetric, encryption-asymmetric

Is there any way to get the same key while encrypting the same data,

For eg: If I have to encrypt a text "bacon" and the encrypted data looks like "e7b75a472b65bc4a42e7b3f78833a4d00040beba796062bf7c13d9533b149e5ec3784813dc20348fdf248d28a2982df85b83d1109623bce45f08238f6ea9bd9bb5f406427b2a40f969802635b8907a0a57944f2c12f334bd081d5143a357c173a611e1b64a"

This encrypted data changes for the same text "bacon"

Is there any way to get this same key as a permanent one for the word "bacon".

Comment: The fact that the ciphertext changes for each encryption, even for the same plain text, is a very **positive** thing. This lets you hide the fact that you've sent the same thing many times, which would let an attacker make some guesses about the data. Why do you want that?

Comment: Which encryption library are you using? ReactJS?

Comment: https://www.npmjs.com/package/cryptr this is the npm I'm using

Comment: I know but in zoom video calling it allows the user to set the same key permanently.And yes, I'm using React JS

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The input key material (the `secret`) doesn't change, but `cryptr`, a one man project on GitHub, uses a random salt to derive the encryption key using PBKDF2 and a random IV for the ciphertext. Both are prefixed to the ciphertext, which also contains a tag as it uses AES-GCM; hence the large ciphertext.

You need to reprogram the simple [`cryptr`](https://github.com/MauriceButler/cryptr/blob/master/index.js) module to use the same salt and IV to get the same ciphertext, but note that if you encrypt other plaintext messages using the same salt and IV you'd be immediately vulnerable against many-time pads and recalculation of the GMAC authentication key (part of GCM).

Currently `cryptr` uses PBKDF2 with a static iteration count to calculate a key from a secret (which may or may not be a password?). It also uses an IV of 16 bytes instead of 96 bits / 12 bytes. This shows that the author doesn't fully understand the cryptography himself if you ask me. Don't use one-man cryptography, and if you want specific properties, program them yourself instead of relying on a higher level library.

Comment: Appreciate your answer, and would like to settle the part about the 128 nonce. I read that if it is generated randomly (not as counter), using a multiple of 128bits results in more usable bits than with the recommended 96bit IV. The implementation of [BouncyCastle](https://github.com/bcgit/bc-csharp/blob/master/crypto/src/crypto/modes/GCMBlockCipher.cs) e.g. will fill it up with a fixed number ´0x01´ when passing a 96bit IV, which seems to be in line with the specification. Is my understanding correct, does a 128bit nonce allow for more usages of the same key?

Comment: Thanks for the fast answer! It's something that bothered me quite a while, so if you could give me your opinion about the footnote of this [answer](https://crypto.stackexchange.com/a/66500/8820) it would be much appreciated.

Comment: A bit too fast, I'm just checking as the result seems to be 128 bits.

Comment: Hmm, weird, it seems to generate 128 bits of randomness. Of course, then it is used as a counter, there is also the chance of overlap, so that makes the issue rather messy.

Comment: Would that mean that for counters the 96bits are mandatory and for random nonces it could indeed be an advantage to use 128bits? I don't expect a fast answer, take your time, I'm really glad to hear your opinion.

Comment: It's answered [here](https://crypto.stackexchange.com/a/80390/1172). For random nonces 128 bit is better. I don't fully agree with Poncho though, if you only have messages of, say,  2^31  or so blocks then 128 bit random is less secure than 96 bits with no possible overlap on the last 32 bits.

Comment: Thank you so much for taking the time!